# Possible paths between two points A and B

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, combinations

**Assume that the following figure represents a map of part of a city very well traced, where the lines are streets. A person is at point A and you want move to point B, but the condition is that you can only choose trajectories through the streets to the right or upwards. According to this condition, how many different trajectories exist to move from point A until point B?**

[image: Figure]

I think that each vertex of each frame that makes up the figure generates two possible movements but I do not know what else to do. Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think that each vertex of each frame that makes up the figure generates two possible movements

This is a good observation but not *quite* true: since the movements are restricted to rightward and upward, once the path reaches a vertex directly below (or to the left of) B, the rest of the path is determined: if the path is directly below B, then no more rightward movement is possible, since this would necessitate future leftward movement to reach B.

In fact, the standard solution to this problem starts from a different observation: the path from A to B will always be a sequence of rightward and upward moves, so can be described as a word made up of the letters R and U. You can convince yourself that the word describing any path from A to B must have nine Rs and nine Us, and, conversely, any word with nine Rs and nine Us describes a unique path from A to B. The problem then becomes to compute the number of words one can make with nine Rs and nine Us; perhaps this is a type of problem you've seen before?

Comment: now I understand! So the answer is $18!$ or $2^{17}$?

Comment: @user402543 If you want to check whether you did everything right, try implementing your method for a smaller case of the same problem; e.g., suppose A and B were separated by 2 rightward and 2 upward moves. It should be easy enough to count the paths by hand, and you can see whether your method gives an answer that matches.

Comment: It does not give me the answer, in that case it would be $2^2=4$ possibilities, what gives me to think that the answer to my initial problem would be $2^9$? I am right?

Comment: @user402543 What about the next case -- 3 rightward and 3 upward?

Comment: @user402543 Was the problem in the analogy I gave, or in your reasoning about the analogous case? Can you count the number of words you can make with two Rs and two Us?

Comment: In the case where I have $4$ paintings, they give me $4$ paths, if I have $9$ squares they give me $10$ paths and if I have $16$ squares they give me $17$ roads. What else can I deduce?

Comment: @user402543 First of all, I'm not sure you're counting correctly. I count $6$ paths for a 2x2, corresponding to words RRUU, RUUR, RURU, UURR, URRU, and URUR.

Comment: the number of words that I can form with two R and two U are $4!$. Am I right?

Comment: @user402543 See my above comment -- I listed $6$. I think I've exhausted them; if there are $4!=24$, what others are there that I missed?

Comment: I also count 6 roads, the ones you are forgetting are not where you can run left and down? (which are not allowed)

Comment: @user402543 I was just asking about words with two Rs and two Us. You said there are $24$; I can't think of more than $6$. What are the ones I haven't thought of?

Comment: I do not know the truth, I have not been able to find them, I'm still looking! Yes there are $24$?

Comment: @user402543 I'm pretty sure there are $6$. Why do you think there should be $4!$?

Comment: Because to form words with two R and two U there are $4$ possible ways to choose the first position, three stops to choose the second, two for the third and one for the last, which gives a total of $(4)(3)(2)(1)$.

Comment: @user402543 You've overcounted. Let's label the two $R$s $R_1$ and $R_2$. You've counted $R_1R_2UU$ and $R_2R_1UU$ as different words (since a different choice is made for the first letter), whereas in reality they are the same word $RRUU$.

Comment: It's true what you say, thanks, is that in this case it would be a permutation and it would be$\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$

Comment: I think I already know how many roads there are in the initial case and those are $\frac{18!}{9!9!}=48620$? Am I correct?

Comment: @user402543 I think so.